# Container scroll without document scroll although resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have `section class"container"` and 5 divs inside it making them re-sizable with jQuery-Ui, i have 3 questions here.

1. How to make the container scrolling when resizing the child divs and the document does not scroll ? **hint: I have tried fixed values for width and height**.
2. Now when I resize a child div it changes it's siblings width, but I need to make each one independent, change it's size and don't change others size.
3. How to create new div (with same siblings classes and dynamic id) when the last div is busy with data?

Here are the code snippets I use:

```js
//$(document).ready(function() {
//    $(".container").draggable().resizable();
// });
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mainContainer").draggable().resizable();
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
     // Hide table and add column view on clicking vertical button
//   $(".liste").hide();
   $("#columnView").hide();
   $(".Vertical").on("click",function(){
       $("div-table-responsive").html("<div id='parent' class='parent-accs container' contenteditable><a id='parent1' href='#' >10100</a><a id='parent1' href='#' >20100</a><a id='parent1' href='#' >30100</a><a id='parent1' href='#' >40100</a></div><div  class='child1-accs container'><div id='child1' class='childs-div'></div></div><div id='child2' class='child2-accs container'></div><div id='child3' class='child3-accs container'></div><div id='details' class='details-accs container'></div>");
   });
   // display childs on clicking parent
   $("#parent1").on("click",function(){
     // function puts childs inside each div
      $("#child1").load("childs.html");
    // Checks whether last display div is empty or not ?!
      if ( $.trim( $('#child3').html() ).length == 0 ) {
        // Create Div when last display div is busy
        $("last-child-has-child").click(function() {
          var domElement = $('<div class="container"><div id="" class="childs-div"></div></div>');
          $(this).after(domElement);
      });
      }

  });
 });
 
// get parent id to know which div are u in
// var i= $(this).closest('div').attr('id'); 


// ajax dynamic load 

//function getPage(id) {
// $('#output').html('<img src="LoaderIcon.gif" />');
// jQuery.ajax({
//  url: "get_page.php",
//  data:'id='+id,
//  type: "POST",
//  success:function(data){$('#output').html(data);}
// });
//}


// chained select : https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/Bemst
```

```css
.mainContainer{
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    background: #ede;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}

/*.div-table-responsive{display:hidden;}*/
.container{

    width: 20%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #EFF0F1;
    display: inline-block;
    
    position: relative;
    margin-left:5px;

    /*left: 250px;*/
    

/*background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin: 10px;*/

/*-moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
    heigh:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;*/
}

.childs-div, #child1{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container a{
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
.container a:hover{color: gray}
.container a:active{color: yellow}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>test new ui for chart of accounts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
    <body>
        print'<section class="container">';
      print'<div id="parent" class="parent-accs container" contenteditable>';
       print' <a id="parent1" href="#" >10100</a>';
        print'<a id="parent1" href="#" >20100</a>';
        print'<a id="parent1" href="#" >30100</a>';
        print'<a id="parent1" href="#" >40100</a>';
      print'</div>';

      print'<div  class="child1-accs container">';
       print' <div id="child1" class="childs-div">';

        print'</div>';
      print'</div>';
      print'<div id="child2" class="child2-accs container">';

      print'</div>';
      print'<div id="child3" class="child3-accs container">';

      print'</div>';
      print'<div id="details" class="details-accs container">';

      print'</div>';
       print' </section>';
    </body>

    <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
      integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>




<!--php file content for dynamic load with ajax-->
<!--
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$pages = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = ".$_REQUEST['id']);
if(!empty($pages)) {
?>
<h3><?php echo $pages[0]['title'];?></h3>
<div><?php echo $pages[0]['content'];?></p>
<?php } ?>-->
```

https://codepen.io/Damasy/pen/YYxzvJ

Comment: Can't clearly understand what have you done and what exactly do you want

Comment: i have a container div, i'd like to make it scroll when childs size get bigger but notice that childs are re-sizable with jquery .resizable()

Comment: Hi,
look at this example, (https://codepen.io/rstrahl/pen/xZErXz)
resize the table columns you will notice that on resizing a column other columns size change, i want to make column resizing independent (does not change any columns size).